# Rysync Log File

Tags: download, rsync, transfer

Im trying to use `rsysnc` to transfer files from my main PC to my server. Once the files are transferred to my server I want to be able to move the files around on my PC and not have `rsync` send them again when I rerun rsync.

I think I can do this by having `rsync` write out a log file with the names of the files it transfers. Then reference that same file as the exclude list.

I'm having trouble getting the format of the log file to be readable as an exclude list. It needs to only print out the file or folder names.

Here is the current command I'm running.

```
rsync -avz --exclude-from=Desktop/file.txt --log-file=Desktop/file.txt --log-file-format=%i Desktop/Source Desktop/Destination
```

What do I need to do to make the log file only output the name of the files or folders?

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the list with a `find . > log.txt` before running rsync

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The issue is that the log file has a lot of other information besides the file name.

Comment: You can filter find on mtime... or only sync the files that have changed since last run